# Android firebase persistencia

Tags: android, firebase

Estoy haciendo una aplicación en android con firebase, pero quiero agregar la opción de poder trabajar offline, leí que es con

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

pero no se como implementarlo ya que estoy obteniendo el siguiente error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main Process:
>   com.example.gabo.empresa, PID: 20190
>   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to
>   setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of
>   FirebaseDatabase instance. at
>   com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.zzsc(Unknown Source) at
>   com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.setPersistence‌​Enabled(Unknown
>   Source) at
>   com.example.gabo.empresa.Vistas.Vista1$6.onClick(Vista1.java‌​:335)

Alguien tendrá un ejemplo de como se hace eso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si ya tienes una aplicación que consulta tu base de datos, si habilitas esta opción funcionaría offline tu aplicación ya que realiza una copia en disco.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
```

Prueba en offline y el accceso a datos se realizaría desde disco!.

**Es importante indicar que se debe habilitar la persistencia del disco antes de que se realicen otras llamadas a la base de datos.**

https://firebase.google.com/support/guides/firebase-android

de lo contrario se puede obtener este error:

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to
>   setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of
>   FirebaseDatabase instance.

Comment: si pero en que parte de la aplicacion la tengo que agregar, el problema es que siempre truena la aplicacion y me dice que el error esta en esa linea.

Comment: Que error es? imagino es que llamas despues de instanciar FirebaseDatabase

Comment: rootProyecto = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("business").child("proyectos");
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);
pues lo declaro asi

Comment: Si pero en el LogCat que error te muestra, ve la edición de mi respuesta, es impotante agregar esa linea antes de usar  la BD!, asegura eso.

Comment: Como te comentó anteriormente @Elenasys, tienes que declararlo antes de hacer mención a las referencias. Haz primero el FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true); Por ejemplo, en el onCreate de tu Application o primera Activity

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.gabo.empresa, PID: 20190
                  com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Calls to setPersistenceEnabled() must be made before any other usage of FirebaseDatabase instance.
                      at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.zzsc(Unknown Source)
                      at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.setPersistenceEnabled(Unknown Source)
                      at com.example.gabo.empresa.Vistas.Vista1$6.onClick(Vista1.java:335)

Comment: Primero habilita la persistencia. =) después consultas. realiza primero; FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

Comment: si ya quedo resuelto haha muchas gracias :D

Comment: Un placer amig@, gracias también a @raeve92, saludos.